# Console showing greek characters as "?" c#

Tags: c#, utf-8

I'm having problems with greek characters in C# because when I run the program, they are replaced either by question marks or by their Latin equivalent. It's the same for the Unicode equivalents.

```
Console.WriteLine("\u03A7\u03BF\u03C5\u03BB\u03B5\u03C4\u03C4");
Console.WriteLine("Χουλεττ");
```

Comment: Which console are you using? Which operating system?

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` <= do this first

Comment: Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; works. Thanks, Rufus! I'm just going to leave it here just in case someone has the same problem.